# Variable for grep and mysql in a bash script

Tags: mysql, bash, grep

I have a bash script with this variable that I then use in a for to copy each of the server databases:

```
bdtocopy = $ (mysql -Ns -uadmin -p`cat / etc / psa / .psa.shadow` -e "SHOW DATABASES" | grep -Ev "^ (horde | apsc | psa | mysql | phpmyadmin_ne2tX0wklnQh | performance_schema | information_schema) $ ")`
```

I would like to separate it, but it doesn't work for me:

`bdtoexclude = $ (horde | apsc | psa | mysql | phpmyadmin_ne2tX0wklnQh | performance_schema | information_schema)
databases = $ (mysql -Ns -uadmin -p`cat / etc / psa / .psa.shadow`-e "SHOW DATABASES")
bdtocopy = $ (echo $ databases | grep -Ev "$ bdtoexclude")`

How would it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pass="$(</etc/psa/.psa.shadow)"
databases="$(mysql -Ns -uadmin -p${pass} -e 'SHOW DATABASES')"
bdtoexclude='^(horde|apsc|psa|mysql|phpmyadmin_ne2tX0wklnQh|performance_schema|information_schema)$'
bdtocopy="$(grep -Ev "${bdtoexclude}" <<< "${databases}")"
```